# Issues with button script in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, touchscreen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovS2o.png)<--- Edit, I narrowed it down to this error that appears when I press build and run on my mobile.

Any ideas why my buttons work in the editor but not on mobile?
My buttons aren't working on my mobile but the do in the editor. Any idea what the problem could be? I thought it might be a text layer in front of it blocking it but that wasn't the case. Thoughts?

The Menu_manager script I'm using is:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class Menu_Manager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button Start_Button;
    public Button Quit_Button;
    public Button Restart_Button;

    public void Start_Game () 
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene (1);
    }

    public void Quit_Game() 
    {
        Application.Quit ();
    }

    public void Restart_Game () 
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene (1);
    }
}
```

Which is confusing because I use the same as my main menu script (just changing what links to where) and it works just fine. SO its not the actual linking the button to the pages but more of the mobile device not recognizing that the button exists.

Comment: how do you setup which button does what?

Comment: Are you sure the scene indexes are set up correctly for Android build?

Comment: So the buttons don't recognise the actual touch. So it isn't a case of clicking on the buton and it takes me nowhere. The buttons are set to grey out when pressed, which isn't happening.

Comment: Edit: I tried shuffling around the UI layers and it ended up working. I'm not 100% sure... I imagine gremlins. But if anyone else experiences this issue make sure things like clear space of pictures aren't over buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The transparent aspects of graphics used above the buttons scaled over them, when converting to a different aspect ratio. So I was tapping on the clear parts of the PNG image.